# Java Threading Concept: Output Explanation

Tags: java, multithreading

Can anyone tell me why is 5 showing up in the following line when I Run the program

```
CURRENT THREAD IS: Thread[main,5,main]
```

The program is from the book, Java Complete Reference and here is the program:

```
public class CurrentThreadDemo 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
System.out.println("CURRENT THREAD IS: " + t);
t.setName("ChangedThreadName");
System.out.println("CHANGED THREAD NAME IS: " + t);

try
{
for(int n = 8; n > 0; n--)
System.out.println(n);
Thread.sleep(1000);
}

catch(InterruptedException e)
{
System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted " + e);
}
}
}
```

The output for the following program is:

```
CURRENT THREAD IS: Thread[main,5,main]
CHANGED THREAD NAME IS: Thread[ChangedThreadName,5,main]
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implicitly calling [`Thread.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString%28%29). The Javadoc for the method indicates that it

> returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.

Looking at the source code confirms this:

```
    return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," + 
               group.getName() + "]";
```

In summary, **the second item is the thread priority**.

On my JDK (and probably on yours), `5` is the value of [`Thread.NORM_PRIORITY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#NORM_PRIORITY).

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Thread#toString()`, it's the priority of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number 5 is the priority of the thread of your program; it has nothing to do with the numbers in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of Thread.toString:

```
 public String toString() {
    ThreadGroup group = getThreadGroup();
if (group != null) {
    return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," + 
               group.getName() + "]";
} else {
    return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," + 
                "" + "]";
}
}
```

As you can see, the '5' is the priority of the Thread.