# Multi-threading output explanation

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
public class thread1 implements Runnable {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    thread1 d = new thread1();
    new Thread(d).start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(d);
    t1.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sleep1(i);
        sleep2(i);
    }
}

public void sleep1(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("sleep 1 and i= " + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void sleep2(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("sleep 2 and i= " + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this is my output:

```
sleep 1 and i= 0
sleep 1 and i= 0
sleep 2 and i= 0
sleep 2 and i= 0
sleep 1 and i= 1
sleep 1 and i= 1
sleep 2 and i= 1
sleep 1 and i= 2
sleep 2 and i= 1
sleep 2 and i= 2
sleep 1 and i= 2
sleep 2 and i= 2
```

Why there is one additional duplicate in each particular sleep and i.

For example:

```
sleep 1 and i= 0
sleep 1 and i= 0
```

Why?

How can i clearly determine that which thread is running at a time and when switched to another thread?

**Edit**

I changed `sleep1()` to `synchronized` and output is this: (Two methods are synchronized)

```
sleep 1 and i= 0
sleep 2 and i= 0
sleep 1 and i= 0
sleep 2 and i= 0
sleep 1 and i= 1
sleep 1 and i= 1
sleep 2 and i= 1
sleep 1 and i= 2
sleep 2 and i= 2
sleep 2 and i= 1
sleep 1 and i= 2
sleep 2 and i= 2
```

I know that to `synchronized` methods can not run concurrently, But how this happens in here?

Comment: `Thread.getCurrentThread().getName()` will help you visualize the threads

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Threading Concept: Output Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064024/java-threading-concept-output-explanation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting two threads

```
new Thread(d).start(); // one here
Thread t1 = new Thread(d);
t1.start(); // another here
```

with the same objects. Both threads will execute `d.run()`. In other words both will call `sleep1` with a value of `i` equal to `1`.

> How can i clearly determine that which thread is running at a time and
>   when switched to another thread?

You can find out by checking the thread's name, but you shouldn't. A thread shouldn't know about itself. It's just meant to run code that you give it.

Comment: Which thread is runs first? what is the name of first thread?

Comment: @Sunrise There is no guarantee on which thread runs first. It's up to the thread scheduler. Use `Thread#getName()` to get the name of a `Thread`.

Comment: @Sunrise `sleep2()` was already `synchronized`. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Sorry, `sleep1()` is now synchronized, too.

Comment: @Sunrise I still don't understand your confusion. You might want to read the [Java tutorial on `synchronized` methods.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Comment: Just to be clear:  "synchronized" will not prevent two or more threads from calling a method.  It will only prevent two or more threads from being in the same method _at the same time._  If the first thread is in sleep1(0) when the second thread tries to enter it, then the second thread will wait for the first one to finish.  After the first one finishes, the second thread is then free to make the same call.

Comment: @jameslarge If you want to reply to someone use `@their-name`. Otherwise, they will not get a notification. (Unless it's on their  question or answer.)